# webcontrols are all null when page is accessed after a redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I've got the following situation. I've created an asp.net website in visual studio 2008. In the root of the website I've got one masterpage and one page old.aspx. I've also got a folder contentpages with a page called new.aspx.
On the new.aspx I've got several web controls. One of them is a dropdown list which gets its datasource in the pageload event. This works perfectly when I visit this pays directly by typing the correct URL.
old.aspx on the other hand is obsolete and should redirect to new.aspx. That's all what old.aspx does these days. However the pageload gets called from new.aspx and all of a sudden it doesn't recognize any of the webcontrols. They're all NULL.
How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you redirecting from old.aspx to new.aspx?  Response.Redirect()?  Are the webcontrols defined in the layout (.aspx) page, or dynamically in the code-behind?

Comment: Try opening a new project, and create 2 .aspx. In the old.aspx redirect it again, in the new .aspx define a dropdownlist and see if it is filled on page load. Try default settings. That will probably work. I guess you changed an attribute of @Page

Comment: @mikemanne I'm using Respone.Redirect() and I defined the webcontrols in the layout section of the page. I don't create them dynamically.

Comment: Rats - was hoping for an easy answer!  :)  If you edit your question to include your pageload function, maybe there's something quirky in there that we might catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something else is going on here. Response.Redirect does exactly the same thing as typing in a URL in the address bar. It will load the page normally without any postback events. I am 100% sure on this. Server.Tranfer works slightly differently.

**Shot in the dark:** Did you by chance copy the file "old.aspx" and paste it in and change the name? Check your "Inherits" attribute on the @Page tag in the markup of new.aspx and make sure it matches the class name in the code behind, as well as the "CodeBehind" attribute. These can get out of whack if you copy files around manually, as its perfectly legal to have a markup page point to a different code behind or class, but it might not be what you intended.

Comment: Nice shot in the dark. I can't confirm if this is the actual problem because I'm currently at home now and I can't check it untill this monday. But I did copy the redirect page from an other project. Perhaps I did missed something in the @Page tag.

Comment: Excellent shot in the dark - this quirk has bitten me before too.  :)  However, if this is the case then the page wouldn't work at all - redirecting to it or typing it directly into the address line.

Comment: That was the solution! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to be of help. This bit me a few times in the past.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to find the controls explicitly. Try something like FindControls